# JavaScript for comparison test between 2 database tables

Tags: javascript, database, compare

I have 2 tables where I would need to perform comparison testing for the following scenario -

```
Table 1
List    ListType    ListValue    User
--------------------------------------   
1       Apple       Grade1       ABC
2       Grapes      Grade2       ABC
3       Orange      Grade3       ABC

Table 2
Order    Apple    Grapes    Orange
-----------------------------------
1        Grade1   Grade2    Grade3
```

I need a javascript to validate the column `ListValue` in `Table1` with row in `Table2`. 
The challenge is - The values in `ListType` in Table1 are columns in `Table2`.

Comment: has T2 only 1 row always?

Comment: Hi @Sam, yes T2 will always have 1 row